# Compute second derivative with GradientTape TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to compute the second derivative of a function (3*x^2+y^2) with respect to two variables ordered as two column matrix, for some reason the first derivative is OK but the second is all wrong

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[-6.0,1.0,2.0,4.0,]])
y = np.array([[-3.0,8.0,9.0,12.0,]])
xy = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.concatenate([x.T,y.T],axis=1))
with tf.GradientTape() as tape2:
    tape2.watch(xy)
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(xy)
        f = 3 * xy[:, 0] ** 2 * xy[:, 1] + xy[:, 1] ** 2
    df = tape.gradient(f, xy)
d2f = tape2.gradient(df, xy)
```

am getting that `d2f`  is:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 2), dtype=float64, numpy=
array([[-54., -34.],
       [ 54.,   8.],
       [ 66.,  14.],
       [ 96.,  26.]])>
```

which is obviously  wrong since the second derivative with respect to y is constant 2.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The way I found to do that is:

```
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape2:
    tape2.watch(xy)
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(xy)
        f = 3 * xy[:, 0] ** 2 * xy[:, 1] + xy[:, 1] **2
    df = tape.gradient(f,xy)
    df_dx = df[:, 0]
    df_dy = df[:, 1]


d2f_dx2 = tape2.gradient(df_dx,xy)[:,0]
d2f_dy2 = tape2.gradient(df_dy,xy)[:,1]
del tape2
```